# Angular 2 *ngFor error: Can't bind to 'menuitemtype' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I created an attribute called `data-menuitemtype` that I'm using in a `div` inside of an `*ngFor` loop. I've never had issues before with creating attributes like this because it is perfectly valid HTML5 syntax, but for some reason `*ngFor` loops don't seem to like it and give me the following error:

> "Can't bind to 'menuitemtype' since it isn't a known property of 'div'".

If I change it to `id` it "works", but then I will have a bunch of id's with the same value which obviously isn't ideal. How can I use created attributes within an `*ngFor` loop without causing errors? Is this possible?

Here is my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties">
    <div class="varietyTypeName menu-item-type-header" data-menuitemtype="{{variety.VarietyTypeName}}">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow-toggle"></i>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, `data-menuitemtype` is not a property, but an attribute and therefore you should use `[attr.insertYourAttributeHere]` in your code, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties">
    <div class="varietyTypeName menu-item-type-header" [attr.data-menuitemtype]="variety.VarietyTypeName">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow-toggle"></i>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Or if you prefer interpolation:

```
<div *ngFor="let variety of varieties">
    <div class="varietyTypeName menu-item-type-header" attr.data-menuitemtype="{{variety.VarietyTypeName}}">
        {{variety.VarietyTypeName}}
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow-toggle"></i>
    </div>    
</div>
```

For more information about difference between attributes and properties, check [Angular 2 Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#).

Comment: That didn't work for me. If I do that then it will always be data-menuitemtype="variety.VarietyTypeName", unless I'm doing something wrong. I want it to be whatever the value of variety.VarietyTypeName is.

Comment: @Brett Another mistake I potentially see is that `data-menuitemtype` is an attribute, not a property and therefore you should use `attr.data-menuitemtype`. I edited my post, check it out.

Comment: There we go. Changing data-menuitemtype to attr.data-menuitemtype did the trick. Thanks!